# Add value to text field on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

First I would like to say Im very noob on RoR.

Im trying to add the value "@example.com" to a text-field on the registration page, so only people with an "example.com" mail could confirm their mail adress. Im using devise gem.

```
<%= f.text_field :email, :style => "font-size:2.0em", :autocomplete => "off" %>
```

If its not possible, another way is verifying the "...@example.com" on the email text box, so an user will not be able to create and confirm an account with another mail.

I already searched for it on internet, but Im new on rails and I couldn't understand well what should I do. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: If you use HTML5, you can use 'pattern'. There, you can add a regex. Something like `<%= f.text_field :email, :style => "font-size:2.0em", :autocomplete => "off", :pattern => "^\w+@example.com" %>` (I know, not a nice one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.email_regexp = /^([\w\.%\+\-]+)@example.com$/i
```

Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1):

If your **f** object have value then it will automatically show in the field else you can put it using **:value => "ABHC"**

Comment: The problem with :value => "ABHC" is the user canjust delete the ABHC and type another thing.

Comment: you mean you don't want to allow the user to edit the value. then put another option :readonly => true

Answer (score 0):

This is a validations problem. You can impose both types of validations(front-end and back-end to fail-proof your function

In User model

```
validates :email, format: { with:     /\A\w+@example\.com\z/, 
                            message: "example.com domains only" }
```

And in the the view file

```
<%= f.text_field :email, :style => "font-size:2.0em", :autocomplete => "off", :pattern => "\A\w+@example\.com\z" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :placeholder => '@example.com'

so your code will be something like this

```
<%= f.text_field :email, :style => "font-size:2.0em", :placeholder => '@example.com', :autocomplete => "off" %>
```

Comment: placeholder will not restrict the input.

Answer (score 0):

in your user model

```
email_regex = /^([\w\.%\+\-]+)@example.com$/i
validates :email, format: { with: email_regex, :message => "email domain must be example.com" }
```